# Show first element in a Tab with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tabs, modal-dialog, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a modal dialog with inside some tabs and contents of this tabs all pre-loaded from a json file (i call him in the js). All works fine except when i open the modal dialog, the first tabs will be active but don't show nothing, only if i click on another tab and then on the first tab the content will show.

This are my code and some samples photos.

[This is when modal dialog is launched first time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3V6w.png)

[This is after click on another tab and then switch back to first, i'll see content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iincN.png)

```
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class ="modal-header">
            <h3 class ="modal-title">Mission's Details Name:{{Items.nome}}{{Items.Mission.nome}} Code:{{Items.codice}}{{Items.Mission.codice}}</h3>
        </div>

        <br>

        <div class="bs-example bs-example-tabs">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li ng-repeat="(key, value) in Items" ng-class="{active: $index == 0}">
          <a href="#tab{{$index + 1}}" data-toggle="tab">{{key}}</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane fade in" ng-repeat="(key, value) in Items" id="tab{{$index + 1}}" ng-class="{active: $index == 0}" >
          <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in value">
                 <b style="color:black;">{{key }}</b> :  <b style="color:dodgerblue;">{{ value}}</b> 
                </div>
        </div>
      </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
            <button class="btn btn-warning" type="submit" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is the js code

```
    var app = angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);

    angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').factory('Service', function() {
      var Service = {
        foo: 'Shared service'
      };
      return Service;
    });

    angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ModalDemoCtrl', function ($scope,$http, $uibModal, $log, Service) {

      alert('Ctrl1');

      $scope.foo = Service.foo;

      $scope.animationsEnabled = true;



      $scope.open = function (size, codice) {

          alert('hai cliccato il bottone numero:' + codice);

            $http.get('./GestioneMissioniServletStep12?codice='+codice)

            .success(function(data){

                $scope.data = data;
                //JSON.parse(data);

                var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
                    animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
                    templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
                    controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
                    size: size,
                    codice: codice,
                    resolve: {
                    Items: function () {
                                return $scope.data;
                           }
                    }
                });
            })

            .error(function(response){
                    alert('Json non Trovato!');
            });
      };

      $scope.toggleAnimation = function () {
          $scope.animationsEnabled = !$scope.animationsEnabled;
      };

    });
    // Please note that $uibModalInstance represents a modal window (instance) dependency.
    // It is not the same as the $uibModal service used above.
    angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $uibModalInstance, Service, Items) {

        $scope.Items = Items;


        $scope.ok = function () {
            $uibModalInstance.close();
        };

        $scope.cancel = function () {
            $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
        };
    });

    app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
        vm = this;
        $http.get("missioni.json")
        .success(function (response) {
            vm.missioni = response.missioni; 

            var aereosoft_bounds = [[41.120228, 14.181791], [41.118632, 14.182596]];
            var areobounds = [[41.120228, 14.181791], [41.129632, 15.182596]];

            var earth = new WE.map('earth_div',{
                sky:true
            });

             $scope.panBounds = function(bounds){
                    alert("ciao");
                    earth.panInsideBounds(bounds);
                }

            WE.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'+
                '<a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
                'Imagery � <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',

            }).addTo(earth);


            angular.forEach(vm.missioni, function(value , key){

    //           f(key + ': ' + value.no);

                marker = WE.marker([value.lat, value.long],value.img, 48, 48).addTo(earth);
                marker.bindPopup("<b class='list'> Mission Cod: </b><b class='p-mission'>" + value.codmis + "</b><br>" +
                                 "<b class='list'> Mission Typecode: </b><b class='p-mission'>" + value.codtipo + "</b><br>" +
                                 "<b class='list'> Mission Name: </b><b class='p-mission'>" + value.nome + "</b><br>" +
                                 "<b class='list'> Mission Info: </b>" +"<button type='button' class='btn btn-info btn-xs' onclick=\"openDiag('"+value.codmis+"')\">Open</button>" + "<br>" +
                                 "<b class='list'>Rating: </b><b class='p-mission'>" + value.rate + "</b><br>", 
                                {maxWidth: 200, closeButton: true})/*.openPopup()*/ ;
            });


        earth.setView([38.341806,4.550849], 5); //Visione del Mediterraneo Originaria
    //  earth.setView([40.857902,14.284191], 18); Visione del Centro Direzionale
    //  earth.setView([40.987849,14.236296], 8);  Visuale a met� tra Napoli e Capua 
    //  earth.setView([36.13343831,-112.10998535], 1);

    /*          var grandcanyon = WE.tileLayer('images/logo_aerosoft.png', {
                  bounds: areobounds,
                  minZoom: 7,
                  maxZoom: 10,
                  tileSize: 23
                });
                grandcanyon.addTo(earth);
    */      

        earth.setTilt(0);
        earth.setHeading(7);
    //  aereosoft.addTo(earth);
    //  earth.panInsideBounds(bounds);

    });



    //function f(x) {
    //alert(x);
    //}



    });

    function openDiag(codmis) {
    /* $http.get("infomissione.json").then(function(response){
        $scope.myData = response.data.infomissione;
    */    
        var scope = angular.element(document.getElementById("ModalDCtrl")).scope();

        scope.$apply(function () {
            codice = codmis;
            scope.open('lg',codice);
        });
    //});
     //angular.element(document.getElementById('ModalDCtrl')).scope().open
    }
```

Comment: Could you share your JavaScript code?

Comment: how are you getting the data? If Angular doesn't know about it (that is, it's not done so the digest loop is aware of it), the content will not be rendered. If that's the case, when you click between tabs, the digest loop fires off, rendering the data. To what @Anzeo said, seeing your JavaScript code would be helpful. Good luck!

Comment: i edit with the JavaScript code! The function $scope.open = function (size, codice)  make a $http get to a Servlet that give back the right json for the input code!